# Error when Building SP Metadata: IDP_CERT_OR_FINGERPRINT_NOT_FOUND_AND_REQUIRED

Tags: saml, onelogin

I am using the [Build SP Metadata](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php) tool and am getting the following error:

> INVALID ARRAY SETTINGS: IDP_CERT_OR_FINGERPRINT_NOT_FOUND_AND_REQUIRED

To repo, go to https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php. In **EntityId**, enter any value, e.g., `https://www.example.com`. For **Attribute Consume Service Endpoint (HTTP-POST)** enter any value, e.g., `https://www.example.com/test`. Then click the Build SP Metadata button at the bottom of the screen.

The result is the aforementioned error. Here are screenshots. The first is of entering the two required fields...

[image: Entering the two required fields.]

And then here's the error:

[image: Error when generating SP metadata]

What am I doing wrong here?